# using VBA to hide various rows based on changing cell value

Tags: vba, hide, rows

I presently have the following coding:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim arCases As Variant
  Dim res As Variant

  arCases = Array("Term", "Indeterminate", "Transfer", "Student", "Term extension", "As required", "Assignment", "Indéterminé", "Mutation", "Selon le besoin", "Terme", "prolongation du terme", "affectation", "Étudiant(e)")

    If Target.Address <> "$C$37" Then Exit Sub


    res = Application.Match(Target, arCases, 0)

    If IsError(res) Then
       Rows("104:112").Hidden = False
    Else
       Rows("104:112").Hidden = True

  End If

End Sub
```

The issue that I am having is that I need to add to this such as if value in Cell C37 is "X" then rows 42:49 are hidden and if value on Cell H4 is "Y" then rows 101:114 are hidden...etc.....

can you advise on how do so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that condition to only execute the code if it matches the cell address, rather than *not* execute the code unless the address is matched.  This will allow you to add further conditions matched on cell address.

I'd recommend changing a hard-coded cell address like "$C$37" to a named range and that named range should ideally be unique throughout the workbook.

`arCases = Array("Term", "Indeterminate", "Transfer", "Student", "Term extension", "As required", "Assignment", "Indéterminé", "Mutation", "Selon le besoin", "Terme", "prolongation du terme", "affectation", "Étudiant(e)")`

```
If Target.Address = "$C$37" Then
    res = Application.Match(Target, arCases, 0)
    If IsError(res) Then
       Rows("104:112").Hidden = False
    Else
       Rows("104:112").Hidden = True
    End If
ElseIf Target.Address = "$H$4" Then
    ' Do something else
End If
```

`End Sub`

Comment: thanks........so where do I add my next "If" statement? If Target.Address = "$H$04" Then

Comment: The second cell reference was, inexplicably, wrong ("$H$04" -> "$H$4").  I've just checked it to make sure it works (it now does).